# Can I use nanoTime instead of randomUUID?

Tags: java

I am writing a process that returns data to a subscribers every few seconds. I would like to create a unique id for to the subscribers:

```
producer -> subsriber1
         -> subsriber2
```

What is the difference between using:

- `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`
- `System.nanoTime()`
- `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Will the nano time always be unique? What about the random UUID?

Comment: Neither will always be unique.  `System.nanoTime` could be the same across two different threads (or if you wait a _very_ long time for overflow...).  `UUID.randomUUID()` _also_ can't always be unique, there's only a fixed number of valid `UUID`s...  But you're statistically _very_ unlikely to get a collision.

Comment: Why do you want to use measures of time instead of a UUID which targets your use case perfectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## UUID

The [128-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit) [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) was invented exactly for your purpose: Generating identifiers across one or more machines without coordinating through a central authority.

Ideally you would use the original Version 1 UUID, or its variations in Versions 2, 3, and 5. The original takes the MAC address of the host computer’s network interface and combines it with the current moment plus a small arbitrary number that increments when the host clock has been adjusted. This approach eliminates any practical concern for duplicates.

Java does not bundle an implementation for generating these Versions. I presume the Java designers had privacy and security concerns over divulging place, time, and MAC address.

Java comes with only one implementation of a generator, for Version 4. In this type all but 6 of the 128 bits are randomly generated. If a cryptographically strong random generator is used, this Version is good enough to use in most common situations without concern for collisions.

Understand that 122 bits is a *really* big range of numbers (5.316911983139664e+36). 64-bits yields a range of 18,446,744,073,709,552,000 (18 quintillion). The remaining 58 bits (122-64=58) yields a number range of 288,230,376,151,711,740 (288 quadrillion). Now multiply those two numbers to get the range of 122-bits: 2^122 = ( 18,446,744,073,709,552,000 * 288,230,376,151,711,740 ) which is 5.3 [undecillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers).

Nevertheless, if you have access to generating a Version of UUID other than 4, take it. For example in a database system such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), the database server can generate UUID numbers in the various Versions including Version 1. Or you may find a Java library for generating such UUIDs, though that library may not be platform-independent (it may have native code within).

## `System.nanoTime`

Be clear that [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) has *nothing* to do with the current date and time. To quote the Javadoc:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.

The `System.nanoTime` feature simply returns a `long` number, a count of nanoseconds since *some* origin, but that **origin is *not* specified**.

The only promise made in the Java spec is that the origin will not change during the runtime of a JVM. So you know the number is ever increasing during execution of your app. Unless reaching the [limit of a `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE), when the counter will rollover. That rollover might take 292 years (2^63 nanoseconds), if the origin is zero — but, again, the origin is not specified.

In my experience with the particular Java implementations I have used, the origin is the moment when the JVM starts up. This means I will most certainly see the same numbers all over again after the next JVM restart.

So using `System.nanoTime` as an identifier is a poor choice. Whether your app happens to hit coincidentally the exact same nanosecond number as seen in a prior run is pure chance, but a chance you need not take. **Use UUID instead.**

Comment: Wow the java doc on System.nanoTime really surprised me. thank you

Answer (score 2):

*java.util.UUID.randomUUID()* is potentially **thread-safe**.

It is not safe to compare the results of *System.nanoTime()* calls between different threads. If many threads run during the same millisecond, this function returns the same milliseconds.

The same is true for *System.currentTimeMillis()* also.

Comparing System.currentTimeMillis() and System.nanoTime(), the latter is more expensive as it takes more cpu cycles but is more accurate too. So UUID should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, you can use `System.nanoTime()` as `id`. I have tested it and did not face with duplication.
**P.S. But I strongly offer you to use UUID.**